# Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Есть база данных Student. Пытаюсь написать CRUD приложение. Методы для создание и отображение объектов работает, но почему то удаление и обновление этих же объектов не работает.

**Ошибка:**

2022-10-29 18:55:38.165  WARN 40287 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

**StudentController:**

```
    package ru.connor.FirstSecurityApp.controllers;
    import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    import ru.connor.FirstSecurityApp.model.Student;
    import ru.connor.FirstSecurityApp.services.StudentService;
    
    import javax.validation.Valid;
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/students")
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class StudentController {
        private final StudentService studentService;
    
        @GetMapping()
        public String showAllClasses(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("students", studentService.showAllStudent());
            return "main/AllClasses";
        }
    
    
        @GetMapping("/{id}")
        public String showById(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
            Optional<Student> student = Optional.ofNullable(studentService.showStudentById(id));
            if (student.isEmpty()){
                return "main/students/errorPage";
            }else model.addAttribute("student", student);;
            return "main/students/index";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/add")
        public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
            return "main/students/new";
        }
    
        @PostMapping()
        public String create(@ModelAttribute("student") @Valid Student student,
                             BindingResult bindingResult) {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
                return "main/students/new";
    
            studentService.addStudent(student);
            return "redirect:/students";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
        public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
            model.addAttribute("student", studentService.showStudentById(id));
            return "main/students/edit";
        }
    
        @PatchMapping("/{id}")
        public String update(@ModelAttribute("student") @Valid Student student, BindingResult bindingResult, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
                return "main/students/edit";
    
            studentService.update(id, student);
            return "redirect:/students";
        }
    
        @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
        public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int id){
            studentService.delete(id);
            return "redirect:/students";
        }
    }
```

**StudentService:**

```
package ru.connor.FirstSecurityApp.services;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import ru.connor.FirstSecurityApp.model.Student;
import ru.connor.FirstSecurityApp.repository.StudentsRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class StudentService {
    private final StudentsRepository studentsRepository;

    public List<Student> showAllStudent(){
        return studentsRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Student showStudentById(int id){
        Optional<Student> foundPerson = studentsRepository.findById(id);

        return foundPerson.orElse(null);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addStudent(Student student){
        studentsRepository.save(student);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(int id, Student person){
        person.setId(id);
        studentsRepository.save(person);
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean delete(int id){
        if (studentsRepository.findById(id).isPresent()){
            studentsRepository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

**HTML в котором написана форма для удаление:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Student</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${student.get().getFullStudentName()}"></h1>
<hr>
<form th:method="DELETE" th:action="@{/students/{id}(id=${student.get().getId()})}">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Никак не могу понять в чем ошибка

Comment: Скорее всего дело в редиректе на /students, почему-то не ловит get запрос, а идет на post. Попробуй разные ендпоинты для пост и гет прописать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно просто поменять ***@PatchMapping/@DeleteMapping*** на ***@PostMapping*** в **StudentsController**. ***@PatchMapping/@DeleteMapping*** используются в только в **RestController**.
Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74271136/20369341

Answer (score 1):

`spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` в настройках спринга

Answer (score 0):

Вместо @Controller поставь @RestController и еще

```
@PostMapping
public String create(@RequestBody Student 
student,@RequestParam BindingResult bindingResult)
```

Comment: Но я же создаю не REST приложение. И у меня метод create работает. Не работает только удаление и обновление этих же объектов.

Comment: Возможно проблемы со связью, с cascade